# Meteor + React issue where once I add a router to my project, it rejects my import from .scss because it expects a node module

Tags: meteor, reactjs, flow-router, react-css-modules

My app works perfectly fine without a router. I'm using the `nathantreid:css-modules` package, which allows modular css for your react components. Within my imports/ui/Navbar directory, I have Navbar.jsx, containing:

```
// Custom Dependencies
import s from './Navbar.scss';
import NavButton from './NavButton/NavButton';
```

When I have the app load the components in client/main.jsx with the following:

```
Meteor.startup(() => {
  render(<App />, document.getElementById('render-target'));
});
```

It works, but it doesn't work when I add either react or flow router and create a route:

```
FlowRouter.route('/', {
  action() {
    mount(App);
  }
});
```

It throws the following:

```
W20160520-10:09:25.659(-7)? (STDERR) Error: Cannot find module './Navbar.scss'
W20160520-10:09:25.659(-7)? (STDERR) at require (packages/modules-runtime/.npm/package/node_modules/install/install.js:78:1)
W20160520-10:09:25.659(-7)? (STDERR) at meteorInstall.imports.ui.Navbar.Navbar.jsx (imports/ui/Navbar/Navbar.jsx:7:1)
W20160520-10:09:25.659(-7)? (STDERR) at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime/.npm/package/node_modules/install/install.js:141:1)
```

Would appreciate any technical insight as to how I might be able to fix this issue.

Also I would like to note that I've tried relative and absolute pathing, but the fundamental issue is that it only looks for NPM packages the moment I add a router (or at least that's my interpretation of what's happening).

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution!

My underlying assumption might be wrong, but I think it has to do with load order. I moved my routes from the standard lib/ folder into my imports/ folder where I also have my other react modules. I then just imported/required the routes in my client/main.jsx and it worked!